# Get type of object when click on webview - Android

Tags: android, webview

I am developing a webview in which i have to define the type of object when i click to this object. For example, when i click to a link, webview understand it is a link and i can get link (returned object); when i click to a image, webview understand it is a image and return image object. I want to get the object type to do some more activities. For example, when i long click to the image, there are some action for me: download, set as background,... when i long click to a link, there are some option like: open in new tab, add to bookmark,... Does anyone know the solution. Thank u very much :)

Comment: Include your attempts also that you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot have direct visibility to the "downside" html/javasctipt from webview listeners.
(WebView reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

However, if you are developing the web application running in the WebView, you can obtain the same result by using JavascriptInterface methods, implementing the javascript methods to "upside" return objects toward android app.

Example interface class:

```
public class JSUpInterface {

    protected Context mContext;

    public JSUpInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getLink(String link) {
        // shows in a toast the clicked link
        Toast.makeText(mContext, link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

WebView attaching:

```
jsUi = new JSUpInterface(context);
webview.addJavascriptInterface(jsUi, "jsui");
```

your html:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" id="a1" onClick="jsui.getLink(this.href);">www.google.com</a>
```

Comment: thank u very much. but my problem is that i cannot interfere to the website. I do not develop app that run on webview. I only view website through webview and do some tasks such as download image, video, open new link in new tab.... :)